# Parse complex String Expression to Boolean in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, boolean-expression

I've got the Task to write a filter for complex and nested JSONs. To do this I need to evaluate Boolean Expressions which the user enters in an input field.
For the sake of the question lets say we have got the following input:

```
(Key1 = "foo" || key2 = 2 && key3 = "bar") && key4 = 7
```

I managed to write a function to evaluate each keyValue-Pair to a either "True" or "False" and replaced them in the string:
e.g.:

```
(True || False && True) && True
```

Now I want to parse this String to a boolean Expression. Is there any "easy" way (built in Function, Plugin) for Javascript which can parse this String?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios `&` is a bitwise AND operator.

Comment: of course its && thanks for the hint!
I changed it in the question

Comment: It is never a Boolean Expression I just created a regexp to get the keyVal Pairs and search them in the JSON. The function returns true or false and I wrote it back in the String. This was just my current approach. I am open to any better idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's `eval()` which is usually not recommended to use but maybe in your case it's suitable. See for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

You could write:

```
eval("(true || false && true) && true") // Returns: 1
```

Note, that I had to rewrite `True` to `true` because `True` is not a recognised as a boolean expression.

However, scopes are applied to `eval()` so I could also write:

```
var True = 1;
var False = 0;
eval("(True || False && True) && True"); // Returns: 1
```

This could work for you if you know the variables in advance I guess. Otherwise, maybe have a look at https://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/ or http://jsep.from.so/.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/joewalnes/filtrex

A simple, safe, JavaScript Filter Expression compiler for end-users

```js
// Input from user (e.g. search filter)
var expression = '(key1 == "foo" || key2 == 2 && key3 == "bar") && key4 == 7';

// Compile expression to executable function
var myfilter = compileExpression(expression);

// Execute function
myfilter({Key1: "foo", key2: 2, key3: "bar", key4: 7}); // returns 1
myfilter({}); // returns 0

// filter an array of objects
var data = [{key1: "foo"}, {key1: "foo2"}];
var results = data.filter(myfilter);
```

the cost of this beauty: 92KByte minified bundle size

i started the project [logic_fn](https://github.com/milahu/logic_fn), to do a similar job in a 1KByte minified bundle, by translating a custom logic expression (with custom operators like &, AND, -) to a javascript expression string, and feeding that to `var f = new Function('input', 'return ' + expression + ';')`. `new Function` is a bit more secure than `eval`, but i still must defend against arbitrary code execution attacks.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using eval, I used http://jsep.from.so/ and then wrote a function to evaluate the output from jsep:

```
function evaluateBooleanExpressionTree(tree) {
    if (tree.type == "Literal") {
        return tree.value;
    }
    else if (tree.type == "LogicalExpression") {
        if (tree.operator == "&&") {
            return evaluateBooleanExpressionTree(tree["left"]) && this.evaluateBooleanExpressionTree(tree["right"]);
        }
        else {
            return evaluateBooleanExpressionTree(tree["left"]) || this.evaluateBooleanExpressionTree(tree["right"]);
        }
    }
    else {
        // Unexpected node parsed
        return null;
    }
}

evaluateBooleanExpressionTree(jsep("(true || false && true) && true"))
// true
```

Comment: working link: https://github.com/EricSmekens/jsep - problem is, jsep does not generate a filter function, that can directly reduce the input data to true or false

Answer (score 1):

[Never use eval()!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

I also wrote a small expression parser for my projects. It's missing a few operators and features but is pretty useful, and super light (1.6k minified)

Here's how it works :

- input an object "subject", and a logical expression string
- find deepest nested parentheses group
- find operators
- process group and replace output in top level group
- loop

https://github.com/nicopowa/operators

```
var myObject = {key1: "foo", key2: 2, key3: "bar", key4: 7};
var myExpression = "(key1 || key2 && key3) && key4";
var result = Operate.parse(myObject, myExpression);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's a perfect place to use `eval`. However, [look through answers to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) to learn about drawbacks of this solution.

- [`eval` reference @ w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)